# How to implement Self Populating EHcache?

Tags: ehcache

Could you please give me the steps to implement SelfPouplatingEhcache.

Regards,
Raju

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelfPopulatingCache` acts as a wrapper (or decorator) around another instance of `EhCache`. When you ask the `SelfPopulatingCache` for a cached value, and that value is not in the underlying cache, the `SelfPopulatingCache` will create the value for you. It does this using the `CacheEntryFactory` that you also provide.

So to create a `SelfPopulatingCache`, you need:

- An instance of `EhCache`, which you fetch from the `ChacheManager`
- An instance of `CacheEntryFactory`, which you write yourself.

Pass them both to the constructor of `SelfPopulatingCache`, and there you are.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer,I am configuring ehcaceh with by xml file.I able to fetch all th ehcahces in my servlet,Here i want to use SelfPopulatingCache to update the cache with some time,How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
SelfPopulatingCache cacheStatus = new SelfPopulatingCache(ehcache, new CacheEntryFactory() {
        @Override
        public Object createEntry(Object key) throws Exception {
            if (key.toString().equals(FLAG1)) {
                 return true;
            } else if (key.toString().equals(FLAG2)) {
                return false;
            }
            return null;
        }
     });
```